# Need to reduce hhline horizontal rule space in left side

Tags: hhline

- How to reduce specific horizontal rule length in the second column using `hhline` package?
- Yellow line in the second column, left side rule width need to reduce.

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%\hangindent6pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|L{50pt}|L{50pt}|L{50pt}|L{50pt}|L{50pt}|L{50pt}|}
Sample 1 &Sample 2 &Sample 3 &Sample 4 &Sample 5&Sample 6\\
Sample 1 &Sample 2 &Sample 3 &Sample 4 &Sample 5&Sample 6\\
Sample 1 &Sample 2 &Sample 3 &Sample 4 &Sample 5&Sample 6\\
Sample 1 &Sample 2 &Sample 3 &Sample 4 &Sample 5&Sample 6\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{blue}\hspace*{10pt}}=>{\arrayrulecolor{red}\hspace*{10pt}}>{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}\hspace*{30pt}}=>{\arrayrulecolor{green}\hspace*{10pt}}===}
Sample 1 &Sample 2 &Sample 3 &Sample 4 &Sample 5&Sample 6\\
\arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any suggestion, please advise?

Comment: Don't use `hhline` for this. It not support what you try to do. Since context of your table is unknown, it is difficult to give any further advice.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your support.